# Django Ajax and Looping over Response

Tags: python, ajax, django

I currently have the following template,

```
{% extends "123/123-base.html" %}
{% block main %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function() {
                    var host = $("#hostinput").val();
                    var record = $("#recordinput").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/lookup_ajax",
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data : {
                            hostinput : host,
                            recordinput : record,
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                        success : function(json) {
                                $('#mainsection').append( "response" + json.response );
                            },
                        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });
                    return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="mainsection">
    <div id="maininput" class="input-append">
        <form method="post" name="inputlookup" action="/lookup_ajax">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <input class="span2" id="hostinput" name="hostinput" type="text">
            <select title="Record" id="recordinput" name="recordinput" >
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="MX">MX</option>
                <option value="Cname">Cname</option>
            </select>
            <button id="button" class="btn" type="submit">Lookup</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="mainouput">
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

However the response I receieve back from the server I want to loop over using the Django template tags, like this,

```
{% extends "123/123-base.html" %}
{% block main %}
        {% if error %}
            {{ error }}
        {% else %}
        <ul>
            <table class="table table-style table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>HOSTNAME</th>
                <th>TTL</th>
                <th>CLASS</th>
                <th>TYPE</th>
                <th>DETAILS</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for answer in response %}
                <tr>
                {% for field in answer %}
                    <td>{{ field }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas on how this should be done ?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you're asking here. Can you provide an example of what you are getting just now and another of what you want the final result to be?

Comment: I basically want to use the variables obtained from the success part of my AJAX jquery funct and use them within my Django template tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you're returning a JSON object for your AJAX call. If that's correct then django doesn't come into it for displaying the result. You'd need to change your `success` function to something like the following:

```
success: function(json){
    // Table header
    var table = $('<table>').addClass('table table-style table-striped');
    var thead = $('<thead>');
    var headrow = $('<tr>');
    var head1 = $('<th>').text('HOSTNAME');
    var head2 = $('<th>').text('TTL');
    var head3 = $('<th>').text('CLASS');
    var head4 = $('<th>').text('TYPE');
    var head5 = $('<th>').text('DETAILS');
    $(headrow).append(head1, head2, head3, head4, head5);
    $(thead).append(headrow);
    $(table).append(thead);

    // table body
    var tbody = $('<tbody>');
    num_answers = json.length
    for (i = 0; i < num_answers; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>');
        var cell1 = $('<td>').text(json[i][0]);
        var cell2 = $('<td>').text(json[i][1]);
        var cell3 = $('<td>').text(json[i][2]);
        var cell4 = $('<td>').text(json[i][3]);
        var cell5 = $('<td>').text(json[i][4]);
        $(row).append(cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4, cell5);
        $(tbody).append(row);
    }
    $(table).append(row);
    $('#mainsection').append(table);
}
```

Comment: Yep I released the error in my question after posting, being that the template is only going to render server side.
Thanks for your response :o)

Comment: Unfortunately I tried your suggestion and when I click submit I only get the JSON printed to the screen (??) Also there are no closing tags ?? Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about no closing tags. jQuery should add them when appending the HTML. Can you post the code from `/lookup_ajax`. I think what is happening is that the JSON yu are returning is not in the format I assumed when I wrote this out, so if you change either a) the format of the JSON returned by `/lookup_ajax`; or b) the jQuery which is building the new output then you should get what you're looking for. Can you post the code from `/lookup_ajax`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
Heres the output,

{"response": [["fir3net.com.", "300", "IN", "A", "149.126.72.43"], ["fir3net.com.", "300", "IN", "A", "199.83.130.66"]], "error": false}